# openai gym env self.observation_shape, self.observation_space, self.action_space use?

Tags: python, openai-api, openai-gym

I need to set the self.observation_shape, self.observation_space, self.action_space in a custom environment in openai gym, the observations i have is just two python lists, the first is  of 8 float elements with the highest value  element being 50 and lowest element value is -50 i.e. [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-0.23,0.11,0.4,0.1] and the second list  is 8 elements of strings i.e.
["n", "n", "s", "c", "n", "b", "n", "n"] only 4 letters is used in the string list n, b, s, c.
No image or rendering is used just lists of values.

the actions are 4, so how can I define the  self.observation_shape, self.observation_space, self.action_space using these lists and actions??